# How to add XML elements from List into XMLEventWriter? Append XML to already created XMLEventWriter/XmlStreamWriter

Tags: java, xml, stax, woodstox, xmlstreamwriter

I have a `List<String>` which contains the `XML` events created as a part of the output from the `JAXB Marshaling` approach. After completion of the `JAXB Marshaling` process this `List<String>` can contain large amounts of XML.

These `XML` fragments so are part of a large XML. The large XML has some additional header elements so I am trying to create the `large XML` using the `XMLEventWriter` and trying to add the elements from my `LIST<String>` but it does not work as expected and running into various errors.

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Trying to output second root
```

Following is the code I have:

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException {
        final XMLEventWriter xmlEventWriter = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventWriter(System.out);
        final XMLEventFactory events = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
        List<String> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
        eventList.add("<fragment><data>First Event</data></fragment>");
        eventList.add("<fragment><data>Second Event</data></fragment>");
        eventList.add("<another><data>Third Event</data></another>");

        xmlEventWriter.add(events.createStartDocument());
        xmlEventWriter.add(events.createStartElement(new QName("root"), null, null));
        xmlEventWriter.add(events.createStartElement(new QName("fragments"), null, null));
        for (String event : eventList) {
            final XMLEventReader xer = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(event));
            if (xer.peek().isStartDocument()) {
                xer.nextEvent();
                xmlEventWriter.add(xer);
            }
        }
        xmlEventWriter.add(events.createEndDocument());
        xmlEventWriter.add(events.createEndDocument());
        xmlEventWriter.close();


    }
}
```

Following is the output I am expecting:

```
<root>
    <fragments>
        <fragment>
            <data>First Event</data>
        </fragment>
        <fragment>
            <data>Second Event</data>
        </fragment>
        <another>
            <data>Third Event</data>
        </another>
    </fragments>
</root>
```

I looked into `XMLStreamWriter` but I got to know that this cannot be done using that. I am not particular about `XMLEventWriter`. All I want to is get the required output using any of the approaches/libraries.

Can someone please help me with this? I just want to add the `XML` from my `List` to `XMLEventWriter` which has been created already with few Nodes.

Comment: I am not sure I see why you think you'd need (or want) to use XMLEventWriter (or -Reader); XMLStreamWriter and XMLStreamReader should work just fine here and have bit lower overhead too. Approach @andreas outlines should work. Event-approach is mostly useful if you need to buffer events for storage or transformations; but for as-you-go generation/translation there's not much value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your ending events are wrong:

```java
xmlEventWriter.add(events.createEndDocument());
xmlEventWriter.add(events.createEndDocument());
```

They should be:

```java
xmlEventWriter.add(events.createEndElement(new QName("fragments"), null));
xmlEventWriter.add(events.createEndElement(new QName("root"), null));
xmlEventWriter.add(events.createEndDocument());
```

---

Second, the issue is that the `xer` event reader ends with an "End Document" event that you don't want copied, so you need to filter it out.

To do that, wrap `xer` with a delegate that ends the event stream when the "End Document" event is reached:

```java
xer = new EventReaderDelegate(xer) {
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (! super.hasNext())
            return false;
        try {
            return ! super.peek().isEndDocument();
        } catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") XMLStreamException ignored) {
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. Indeed it worked. I have been trying to rectify it since afternoon without any progress. Just out of curiosity do you have some sort of documentation where you found this? or with your knowledge? I just wanted to know where can I find something like this. Thanks a lot again, you deserve the upvote and accepted answer. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Also, one more question. I am using the `XMLEventWriter` to create a large XML. The `List<String> eventList` can contain 1000s of entries is this the best choice or there something better than this that I can use? I was previously using `XMLStreamWriter` but later I found that I cannot do something similar using that so I switched to `XMLEventWriter`. Just wanted to confirm if this is the most efficient and effective for handling large XML.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 I just looked at the javadoc of [`XMLEventReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html) and saw the `EventReaderDelegate` listed as a known implementing class. Then I created a test program (copy of your code), wrapped `xer` and implemented some of the methods with a print statement, so I could see how it was used. Only `hasNext()` and `nextEvent()` was called, so it was easy to figure out that simply tweaking `hasNext()` could be used to prevent the EndDocument event from being returned.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 Using `XMLEventWriter` is good. But where does `eventList` come from. You mentioned that the strings are a result of JAXB Marshaling, and the [`Marshaller`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html) can [`marshal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshal-java.lang.Object-javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter-) directly to an `XMLEventWriter`, so it might be possible to skip the entire intermediate XML String. Alternative, marshall to string, but then do the `xer` thing immediately, instead of building a list.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I will also try to figure out the same using methods you have mentioned just to learn. With regards to `List`  question, yes its created after marshaling but after marshaling actually i need to verify if it matches the prescribed `XSD`. Hence, I am using `Stringwriter` within `Marshaling`. After which this StringWriter content validated against XSD. If it validates I am writing into `ArrayList`. This happens for large number of events. Basically I am converting JSON to XML using marshling approach.

Comment: So after all the events are read from JSON and Converted to XML, I need to create the Header for the XML and write these Matshaled events one by one. Hence I am creating the List first and then XMLEventReader for creating final XML using the fragments of XML in the List. Is there better approach? I hope i have explained correctly so you can understand whats the background. Looking forward to your suggestions or improvements

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 I already told you the better approach: Write it as you go. Marshall the first XML, validate it, write it to final XML stream. Repeat for next XML. No list build-up = reduced memory use.

Comment: I am running into an issue while using the `XMLEventWriter`, If you get a chance can you please have a look at this issue and provide me with some resolution? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69028368/7584240