# XMLEventWriter throws javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: No open start element, when trying to write end element even though opened

Tags: java, xml, stax, woodstox, xmlstreamwriter

I have a application `JSON -> XML` converter. This application will take a `List` of events that are converted to XML one by one. Before conversion, the header for the final XML will be created using the `start` method, and later converted events are added to `xmlEventWriter` one-by-one, and finally after all the conversion the closing tags are added to the XML using `end` method.

I am facing an issue during the closing of tags and running into the error:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: No open start element, when trying to write end element
```

As per my understanding, everything is correct but still facing the issue don't know why.

Following is the class that will create the `header body and closure` tags in XML:

```
public class EventXMLStreamCollector implements EventsCollector<OutputStream> {

    private final OutputStream stream;
    private final XMLEventWriter xmlEventWriter;
    private final XMLEventFactory events;

    public EventXMLStreamCollector(OutputStream stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
        try {
            xmlEventWriter = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventWriter(stream);
            events = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            throw new EventFormatConversionException("Error occurred during the creation of XMLEventWriter : " + e);
        }

    }

    public void collect(Object event) {
        System.out.println("COLLECT START");
        try {
            XMLEventReader xer = new EventReaderDelegate(XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(event.toString()))) {
                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    if (!super.hasNext())
                        return false;
                    try {
                        return !super.peek().isEndDocument();
                    } catch (XMLStreamException ignored) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            };
            if (xer.peek().isStartDocument()) {
                xer.nextEvent();
                xmlEventWriter.add(xer);
            }
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            throw new EventFormatConversionException("Error occurred during the addition of events to XMLEventWriter: " + e);
        }
        System.out.println("COLLECT END");
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream get() {
        return stream;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Map<String, String> context) {
        System.out.println("START START");
        try {
            xmlEventWriter.add(events.createStartDocument());
            xmlEventWriter.add(events.createStartElement(new QName("doc:Document"), null, null));
            xmlEventWriter.add(events.createNamespace("doc", "urn:one"));
            xmlEventWriter.add(events.createNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchem-instance"));
            xmlEventWriter.add(events.createNamespace("cbvmda", "urn:two"));
            
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> stringStringEntry : context.entrySet()) {
                xmlEventWriter.add(events.createAttribute(stringStringEntry.getKey(), stringStringEntry.getValue()));
            }

            xmlEventWriter.add(events.createStartElement(new QName("Body"), null, null));
            xmlEventWriter.add(events.createStartElement(new QName("EventList"), null, null));
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            throw new EventFormatConversionException("Error occurred during the creation of final XML file header information " + e);
        }
        System.out.println("START END");
    }

    @Override
    public void end() {
        System.out.println("END START");
        try {
            System.out.println(xmlEventWriter.toString());
            xmlEventWriter.add(events.createEndElement(new QName("EventList"), null));
            xmlEventWriter.add(events.createEndElement(new QName("Body"), null));
            xmlEventWriter.add(events.createEndElement(new QName("doc:Document"), null));
            xmlEventWriter.add(events.createEndDocument());
            xmlEventWriter.close();
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            throw new EventFormatConversionException("Error occurred during the closing xmlEventWriter:" + e);
        }
        System.out.println("END END");
    }

    @Override
    public void collectSingleEvent(Object event) {
        try {
            XMLEventReader xer = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(event.toString()));
            if (xer.peek().isStartDocument()) {
                xer.nextEvent();
            }
            xmlEventWriter.add(xer);
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            System.out.println("ADDED : " + e.getMessage());
            throw new EventFormatConversionException("Error occurred during the addition of events to XMLEventWriter: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error for this line:

```
xmlEventWriter.add(events.createEndElement(new QName("Body"), null));
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. I am opening the `Body` tag and then trying to close it. I am sure that the flow is correct, I am calling `start`, `collect`, and then finally `end`. Following the `output` I am getting:

```
START START
START END
COLLECT START
COLLECT END
END START
```

I am not getting `END END` because of the error I am getting for the `closing of Body` tag. Can someone please help me understand this issue and provide some workaround and help.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for the case that is failing for you? What are you passing to each method, especially the collect method?

I tested the start() and end() methods and both seem to work fine and generate a valid xml, with doc:Document, Body and EventList correctly opened and closed.

Comment: @DragosGeornoiu Thanks a lot for your response and comment. Actually, I tried debugging further and found that it's not this class that's causing the issue. The issue actually lies in another `Jackson` class which is calling these methods after deserialization. I have posted the question here if in case you have some idea please provide some response: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69039319/7584240